# Create landscape tables with apa6 document class

Tags: tables, landscape, apa6

How can I create landscape tables with the apa6 document class? The `landscape` environment seems to be ignored; the table is still upright. I guess the problem is that tables and figures are automatically moved to the end of the document. Is there a way to have landscape tables anyway?

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %landscape pages
\shorttitle{foo}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[tp]
\captionbox{Some table}
{\begin{tabular}{cc}\toprule
\textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\ \midrule
foobar & 1 \\
foobaz & 2 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you specifically need a solution for apa6 and that has a modified float definition, you should probably edit your MWE to use that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotating package `sidewaystable` environment appears to be compatible with this class.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %landscape pages
\usepackage{rotating}
\shorttitle{foo}

\begin{document}
Some text


\begin{sidewaystable}[tp]
\captionbox{Some table}
{\begin{tabular}{cc}\toprule
\textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\ \midrule
foobar & 1 \\
foobaz & 2 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```